# What are Finder Smart Folders?

Tags: macos, finder, storage, smart-folders

What are smart folders in the macOS Finder?

What can they do, and how do you use them?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This site isn't really suited to provide tutorials on Apple features.  I would recommend you start with [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-or-change-a-smart-folder-on-mac-mchlp2804/mac) and then if you have a specific problem in using them, come back here and use the Search function for previous Answers.

Comment: Such questions fit in SO/ SE when 1. OP is preparing a self answer 2. The documentation and tutorials are not clear or thorough enough. Neither is the case here. One should approach Apple Support articles and macOS manual first. As CJK mentioned below, if edited to ask the underlying mechanism, I’d vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different. Smart Folders are folders that are occupied by a search action. The smart folder finds and organizes the results of a find operation. Another more descriptive answer is found [here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/use-smart-folders-mac-os-x) and [here](https://www.cultofmac.com/48911/100-tips-19-what-are-smart-folders/).

You create a smart folder by going to the Finder and then selecting create a smart folder from the File menu. The smart folder looks like the image below.

[image]

By clicking the + button you below the search bar you can add more criteria to your search. Hence you can fine-tune the contents of your smart folder.

Comment: It does answer the question @lx07, but merely lacks thoroughness.  Whomever downvoted this answer is a bit unfair.  The guy went to the effort of including screenshots, _and_ linking two related answers that the OP really should have searched for themselves before asking a really banal question for which there are already infinite places to find different answers. Anyway, +1 from me for the underappreciated guy helping out someone who I hope upvotes as well to say Thank You.

Comment: I have to agree with CJK comment, it does lack thoroughness. I do not particularly like bolstering the answer with links that could become dead, verse a more thorough answer, however I'll give it a +1 because it gives the OP more information then they had before posting the question.

Comment: I assumed such a find-it-yourself question that the person who asked it wanted a simple answer to what it is.  Not a page-long explanation that may be the questioner wouldn't understand and which I couldn't give anyway.  Thanks to you both for covering for me and your upvotes.  If my answer is excepted I suppose the OP got the answer he was looking for. If not then I suppose he didn't.  @lx07 is welcome to write his own answer.

Comment: Shame it's been put on hold.  I was going to approach from a totally different angle and show the OP the inner core of a smart folder, by taking apart its XML.  This is the only way one can create smart folders that scour multiple folders in disparate locations.  A simple script to generate the XML according to one's needs is far more powerful than the available options built into finder.

Comment: i sure couldn't have written that.  But it would be an interesting read.  Thanks...